# Is Mjolnir actually capable of flying back into Thor's hand like a boomerang after being thrown?

Tags: norse, thor, mjolnir

This is something [Marvel's Thor does all the time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76334/what-kind-of-pathfinding-system-does-mjolnir-use/76336#76336):

[image]

So I was wondering: **Has Thor/Mjolnir ever done anything like this in actual Norse mythology?**

Comment: This is another "experimental" question. This time the motivation came from chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21461087#21461087

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it seems so.  In the Prose Edda, when Thor is presented with the hammer by Brokkr, this property is in the description ([Page 147, here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/pre/pre05.htm)):

> Then he gave the hammer to Thor, and said that Thor might smite as hard as he desired, whatsoever might be before him, and the hammer would not fail; and if he threw it at anything, it would never miss, and never fly so far as not to return to his hand;

Comment: I'm honestly shocked that this is in the original mythos. Thanks for digging that up.